# How to disable selected date and time in jQuery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetime, datetimepicker

I am using jQuery [datetimepicker](https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/). Date picker is added to book a date and time. Here is how it should work.

Enable date picker from Sunday to Saturday except Wednesday and time is 8am to 6pm
On Tuesdays available times are 8am to 2pm

When someone makes booking for date with time that should not be available for others and for that I am trying to use disabledDates but not working.

Here is the script

```
function DisableWed(date) {

    var day = date.getDay();
    // If day == 1 then it is Wednesday
    if (day == 3) {

    return [false] ; 

    } else { 

    return [true] ;
    }
  }
$('#pickdate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'Y-m-d H:s',
    beforeShowDay: DisableWed,
    minDate: 0,
    disabledDates: ['2016-11-03 09:00'],
    allowTimes: ['08:00','09:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','13:00','14:00','15:00','16:00','17:00']
});
```

As described http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ minTime and disabledDates seem not working for me.

Comment: can you add a fiddle

Comment: Thanks @SusheelSingh for the response :) and here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/matatitung/66uvybb8/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do beforeShowDay to disable Wednesday, if you look at the doc, they do have disabledWeekDays for you.

```
disabledWeekDays: [3] // will disable Wednesday
```

You then use onChangeDateTime to check the date user click, so that you can reset the allowed times base on user's choice.

```
 onSelectDate:function(dp,$input){ // this will switch available time when choose the day
  if (dp.getDay() == 2) {
    this.setOptions({
      allowTimes: ['08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00']
    });
  } else {
    this.setOptions({
      allowTimes: ['08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00']
    });
  }
```

You also do an if statement for initial allowed times to check if current day is Tuesday or not, it Tuesday, initial allowed time is 8am-2pm, if not 8am-6pm

```
allowTimes: new Date().getDay() == 2 ? ['08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00'] : ['08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00'], // this we show 8am-2pm if today day is Tuesday
```

See my [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/trungkim2201/cdj4njre/)

Comment: Thank you so much Trung Huynh. This really works for me. Now the only thing I could not make work is disabledDates. Even if I add disabledDates list, they are not working. I am not sure if I am doing this in wrong way, you can see the fiddle I have provided. When someone books date such as "2016-12-12 09:00" then this date and time should be disabled while clicking no date picker. Is this something I need to add on onChangeDateTime event?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @user75472 I dont really understand what you really want to do with disabledDates. Please give me a better idea what do you exactly want to be done.

Comment: I have a booking site for class. If someone books class for lets say 2016-12-12 9:00 then that date/time should be disabled for others. Does this make sense. Please let me know if this needs to be explained.

Thanks

Comment: @user75472 Ok I understand it now, working on it. look like nothing on the doc allow us to do it, will let me know if i figure it out

Comment: Thanks @trung-huynh. I am not 100% but I think it also depends on the version of the datetimepicker so I am trying with different versions or may be I need to look for another option if there is any. if you have any idea about other date time picker plugin, do let me know

Comment: @user75472 please accept the answer if it helps you. Thanks

Comment: my question was to fix disabledDates issue and this is still not working. However this helped me to fix allowTimes and disabledWeekDays in different way than I did. And I have already marked as Useful answer. Thanks